# Background Image disappears when scrolling in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar at the top of my website.  Every time I scroll down, what seems to be past 100% of the height of the window, the background image disappears.

[Here is an example of the issue.](http://david.ingledow.co.uk/blog/apples-leather-iphone-case/)

The functionality works fine in Safari!

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="/work/">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="nav_bg">
</div>

div.nav_bg{
    height: 72px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    z-index: -10;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    background-image: radial-gradient(transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.4)),
                  url(http://ingledow-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/media/blog/2014/05/18/DSCF6517.jpg);
}
```

Comment: try this **position:fixed;**

Comment: In Chrome it also looks fine, can't see an issue. But in IE there is nothing where it should be...
in which browser you had the problem?

Comment: Are you talking about your home page? Your picture didn't render properly for me in safari; it worked fine in chrome.